# Search in all store views in Magento 2.4

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

I have a magento 2.4.4 install with 2 store views, English and Arabic, however when i search in Arabic store for any product in English letters, it show no results, how i can make the search function to work in all store views, so whenever the user search in any language it should show products from across the stores.

Answer (score 0):

there is one idea you can do it which is creating a product attribute and then in each product add the full name of product in all the languages in the same field.

the steps :

navigate to **Stores > Attributes > Product > Add New Attribute**

fill **Default Label** field

choose the **input type**: **Text Field**

choose **Scope** : **Global**

then navigate to **Storefront** Properties on the left

change **Use in Search** to **Yes**

click **Save Attribute**

**now reindex and flush cache**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

now navigate to **Stores > Attributes > Attribute Set > default** (or your custom attribute)

add the attribute that you just done from **Unassigned Attributes** section then click **save**

now you need to edit every product

in product edit page you will see now the attribute that you have done

add the full name in all the languages for example :

Iphone 14 pro max purple ايفون 14 برو ماكس بنفسجي ليلكي

you can add any word to use it in searching

click **save**

**now reindex and flush cache again**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

now from any storeview you can search **ايفون** or **iphone** and it is the same result

hope that helps